# dc.js bubble chart fails to display points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter, bubble-chart

I am trying to get a bubble chart working with crossfilter and dc.js.  But I am having a problem getting my points to appear on my chart.  I have built a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4asmb7h1/

```
var data = [
    {date: "12/27/2012", label: "a1", x: 2, y: 190, bubble: 5},
    {date: "12/28/2012", label: "a2", x: 2, y: 10,  bubble: 5},
    {date: "12/29/2012", label: "a3", x: 95, y: 300, bubble: 10}
];
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});
var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
var xDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.x;});
var bubbleChart  = dc.bubbleChart("#bubble-chart"); 
bubbleChart
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(xDim)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]))
    .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]))
    .width(400)
    .height(400)
    .yAxisPadding(50)
    .xAxisPadding(50)
    .xAxisLabel('X') // (optional) render an axis label below the x axis
    .yAxisLabel('Y') // (optional) render a vertical axis lable left of the y axis
    .label(function (p) {
        return p.label;
    })
    .renderLabel(true)
    .title(function (p) {
        return [
               "x: " + p.x,
               "y: " + p.y,
               "Bubble: " + p.bubble,
               ]
               .join("\n");
    })
    .renderTitle(true)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true) // (optional) render horizontal grid lines, :default=false
    .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
    .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.3)
    .keyAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.y;
    })
    .valueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.x;
    })
    .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.bubble;
    })
;
```

The data is viewable via the data table at the bottom, so I know the data is being seen.  My best guess at this point is that I am not implementing my groups or dimensions properly, but nothing I seem to try is working for me.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?  I am looking for the points to be displayed as data.x, data.y with a bubble size of data.bubble.

EDIT: updated the question to include more setup JS. (All code is on my fiddle)

Comment: I apologize, but just asking others to debug your code doesn't make a great SO question. In particular, you'll want to 1. Look at the debug console for any errors 2. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#tell-whether-my-groups-are-functioning-correctly--whether-my-input-data-is-good 3. The debugger in your browser is your friend.

Comment: I am not trying to get you to debug my code.  As I stated, I think I understand where my problem was (groups/dimensions).  This is not actually my "code" as much as a fiddle to try and reproduce the issue.  I have greatly simplified the code to try and make it easier.  There are no console errors.  I think it is clear that I am having trouble with the grouping as it is the portion of the code that I understand the least.

Comment: Wow, it looks like you found a pretty odd corner case of dc.js.  It shouldn't be possible to pass in a dimension as a group.  It just happens that they both have a `.top` function, so that's why it didn't generate any errors.  Ugh.

Comment: Gordon, yea so this came about after many attempts to get this working and was probably introduced into my code as a copy-paste error.  I don't suspect many people will do this, but maybe there is a check that could be put in place to force a check to see if a group is being passed in?  Perhaps have a isGroup(){return true} method on the base group class or something (this seems a bit hackish to me though, it's really too bad JS does not support type hinting.

Comment: Well, it's funny because a lot of people actually substitute in other objects that look like the right objects (see for example the "fake group" pattern, and the people who don't use crossfilter at all). Maybe the best way would be to have a console warning if the passed-in objects do not match the expected interface, which people could disable. I have been thinking about formalizing the internal interfaces, so I could do it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see a few things wrong:

1. In the bubble chart, you are passing a dimension in as a group parameter.  `dc.js` would expect you to pass in a previously declared group to that parameter.
2. It doesn't look like you're actually using the benefits of `crossfilter` here.  The idea is to group up and summarize your data.  Your dimensions result in a unique value being created for each value of the dimension, which is OK, but it kind of misses the point of `crossfilter`.
3. When you're referencing the properties of the grouped object, you're not referencing them correctly.  When `crossfilter` groups items, it will create new objects with `key` and `value` properties containing the key (matches a `dimension` value) and a value (computed from the `reduce` function).  You're not using these properties from the grouped object.

Having said all that, here is a `jsfiddle` that may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/0w3xnbu0/5/

I think I've generated what it is you're after.

The changes I've created are:

1. Created a `dateGroup` object which groups and reduces your data so the `bubbleChart` can load it.  This is potentially not correct, especially if your real data includes multiple records with the same date.  To adapt this to other datasets, you'll definitely need to change the functions in the `reduce` part of this object.

   ```
   var dateGroup = dateDim.group().reduce(
       function(p, v) {
           ++p.count;
           p.label = v.label;
           p.bubble = v.bubble;
           p.x = v.x;
           p.y = v.y;

           return p;
       },
       function(p, v) {
           --p.count;
           p.bubble = 0;
           p.label = "";
           p.x = 0;
           p.y = 0;

           return p;
       }, function() {
           return { count: 0, x: 0, y:0, label: "" };
       });
   ```
2. Created an `xRange` and `yRange` object that correctly sets the `min` and `max` values of your `x` and `y` values, rather than just hardcoding to `[0, 100]`.

   ```
   var xRange = [-10, d3.max(dateGroup.all(), function(d) { return d.value.x + d.value.bubble*2; }) ],
       yRange = [-10, d3.max(dateGroup.all(), function(d) { return d.value.y + d.value.bubble*2; }) ];
   ```
3. Updated the bubbleChart object to use the new dateGroup and x and y scales on the bubbleChart call to use the new ranges above

   ```
   bubbleChart
       .dimension(dateDim)
       .group(dateGroup)
       .x(d3.scale.linear().domain(xRange))
       .y(d3.scale.linear().domain(yRange))
   ```
4. Changed the `title`, `keyAccessor`, `valueAccessor` and `radiusValueAccessor` functions of the `bubbleChart` to correctly reference the appropriate values from the grouped object.

   ```
       .title(function (p) {
           return [
              "x: " + p.value.x,
              "y: " + p.value.y,
              "Bubble: " + p.value.bubble,
              ]
              .join("\n");
       })
   ...
       .keyAccessor(function (p) {
           return p.value.x;
       })
       .valueAccessor(function (p) {
           return p.value.y;
       })
       .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
           return p.value.bubble;
       })
   ```

Comment: Ben, thanks a lot for this write-up.  I'll be playing around with it this morning.  You are correct that I am not using crossfilter in the example I worked up, but that is mainly due to me trying to simplify my code down for readability.  I will need crossfilter in my final code to filtering other associated meta data (Dates, etc).